# In Arch Linux WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) what is the workaround for

Tags: arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
fakeroot, while creating message channels: Function not implemented
This may be due to a lack of SYSV IPC support.
fakeroot: error while starting the `faked' daemon.
```

I saw a post with a workaround like this for Ubuntu/Debian based distros:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set fakeroot /usr/bin/fakeroot-tcp
```

So, is there an equivalent in Arch?

Comment: I'm using Arch, Ubuntu, Debian,.... and others in WSL. It runs without any fakeroot workaround. If you're new to WSL world you can try this https://github.com/yuk7/ArchWSL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the ArchWSL package that was mentioned above. As you said, the workaround is to use fakeroot-tcp. Since you can't use the package on aur to do that, you just need to follow the steps in the [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=fakeroot-tcp). Basically, they're (currently):

1. Download the latest fakeroot `.tar.xz` package from Debian: http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fakeroot/. The aur package also provides a patch that appears to silence some errors. You can download it from [aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/?h=fakeroot-tcp).
2. Make sure you have all the dependencies. They're listed by `depends=` and `makedepends=` on the PKGBUILD.
3. Extract the tarball. `tar -xf` works fine. Change to the directory with the newly extracted source.
4. If you want to do the patch: `$ patch -p1 -i path/to/silence-dlerror.patch`.
5. `$ ./bootstrap.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/fakeroot --disable-static --with-ipc=tcp`
6. `$ make`, then `# make install`
7. `# echo '/usr/lib/libfakeroot' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/fakeroot.conf`
8. `# install -Dm644 README /usr/share/doc/fakeroot/README`